# TabLayout and Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-appcompat, android-tablayout

I am trying to implement a TabLayout in Xamarin Android.

However when I try to construct a TabLayout I get the following exception

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat them (or descendant) with the design library.

I have tried this with the TabLayout in an .axml layout but when I inflate it I get the exception.

I also tried taking it out of the .axml layout file and programmatically adding it to the view after I inflated. In this case I get the exception directly after calling

```
var tabLayout = new TabLayout(Application.Context);
```

I have also set the theme to Theme.AppCompat in the AndroidManifest file

I have spent two days on this and need some help, it would be useful if someone had a very simple working example they could share.

I am using Xamarin and MvvmCross.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: No, none of these have worked for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you have added a Theme to your AndroidManifest.xml. Depending on what node you assign it to, it might get overwritten on build time, by what is specified in the `[Activity]` attribute on your `Activity`.

Normally in Xamarin.Android you would add it to the `[Android]` attribute instead of manually editing the manifest.

You can check your resulting manifest in `obj\android` and see whether it still contains the Theme you have set. Otherwise add it like so:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyActivity", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
public class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

This way it will get added correctly on build time to the manifest.

Comment: I don't know what happened but I put the tabLayout back into the .axml file and gave it a style of Theme.AppCompat and it now inflates. Not quite sure why it's working but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened but I put the tabLayout back into the .axml file and gave it a style of Theme.AppCompat and it now inflates. Not quite sure why it's working but it is working.